# Getting around making constructor call the first statement in a constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am a Java newbie, hence the simple question:

I have a class whose constructor takes one argument as follows:

```
class MyBase {
    public MyBase(ObjectType1 o1) {}
    ...
}
```

I want to derive a class from this class whose constructor takes a string and calls the constructor of the base class with the proper argument chosen on the basis of this argument as follows:

```
class MyDerived extends MyBase {
     public MyDerived(String objectType) {
          ObjectType o = null;
          if (objectType.equals("type1")
              o = A; /* some value */
          else
              o = B; /* some other value */

           super(o);
     }
```

The problem with this code is obviously that constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor. So how do I solve this problem? I don't want to make the decision about `ObjectType` outside `MyDerived`. I would also prefer to avoid having to provide a static `CreateObject` method for `MyDerived`.

Comment: What's wrong with the static method?  It's a clean solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're reinventing Enums.

```
class Base {
    static enum Option {
        alpha, beta, gamma;
    }

    public Base(Option o) {
        // ...
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public Derived(String s) {
        super(Option.valueOf(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Define a static helper method in your class, and call that.  e.g.:

```
class MyDerived extends MyBase {
     public MyDerived(String objectType) {
           super(myHelper(objectType));
     }

     private static ObjectType myHelper(String objectType) {
         ...
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case could just use the conditional operator:

```
class MyDerived extends MyBase {
    public MyDerived(String objectType) {
        super(objectType.equals("type1") ? A : B);
    }
}
```

In more complex scenarios, you can use a separate method, as shown in Oli's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyDerived(String objectType) {
    super( (objectType.equals("type1") ? A : B) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a static method like this

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    new MyDerived("one");
    new MyDerived("two");
}

}

class MyBase {
public MyBase(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}
}

 class MyDerived extends MyBase {
 public MyDerived(String objectType) {
       super(getType(objectType));
 }

private static Object getType(String type) {
    Integer integer = null;
     if (type.equals("one") ) {
          integer = 1; /* some value */
    } else {
          integer = 2; /* some other value */
    }

    return integer;
}
}
```